# Calculating the integral of a derivative

Tags: calculus

I have been trying to understand how the integral of the derivative of a function is the difference in the value of the function evaluated at the upper and lower limits.
$$\int_a^xf'(t)\,\mathrm dt=f(x)-f(a)\tag{1}$$

Can someone explain how the above relation is written?

Comment: It's the [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Formal_statements). If you want to understand where it comes from, you will need to first study [Riemann sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum).

Comment: $$\int_a^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt=F(x)-F(a),\tag{1}$$ from fundamental theorem of calculus. But ,I am not able to understand how $$\int_a^xf'(t)\,\mathrm dt=f(x)-f(a),\tag{1}$$ followsfrom the above relation

Comment: If \begin{align} G' &= g \\ \implies G &= \int g dx \quad (1) \end{align} then setting $g = f'$ implies \begin{align} G' &= f' \quad (2) \\ \implies G &= \int f' dx \quad \text{from $(1)$} \\ &= f \quad \text{from $(2)$} \end{align} up to a constant. Using the fundamental theorem of calculus, we evaluate the integral at it's limits.

Comment: This clarifies my doubt.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This$$\int\limits_a^bdx\, f(x)=F(b)-F(a)$$is just the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. Here, $f(x)$ is obviously the function you want to integrate and $F(x)$ is any function whose derivative is $f(x)$.

Concerning your question, when $f'(x)$ is integrated, the result is $f(x)$ because the antiderivative of a derivative is the function itself (up to an additive constant - provided the function is continuous, differentiable everywhere, etc.) Therefore$$\int dx\, f'(x)=f(x)$$And add the limits using the theorem before and you get the equation in your question.

Answer (score 1):

By [The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus), a definite integral is the difference of the indefinite integral, the antiderivative, evaluated at the two end points. Then $\int f'(t) dt = f(t)$. The last step of plugging in the end points is done in OP's expression.